# Java date parsing issue

Tags: java, datetime

I have an exception in parsing a date from a string:

> java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "16 May 2013 19:27:12" (at
>   offset 3)

but i think that i'm using the right pattern:

```
SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss");

try {
    done = true;
    date = simpleDateFormat.parse(dateString);
} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    done = false;
}
if (done) {
    return date;
}
```

Somebody can help? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The problem is the interpretation of "May" because you did not specify any locale.

Try :

```
SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss", new Locale("en_US"));
```